# Draft.js Best Practices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rich-text-editor, draftjs

**Questions:**

1. What's the best way to save Draft.js text to database? ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41634473/9464680))
2. How to limit break lines (vertical space) to reduce size of EditorState? ([related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42993638/9464680))

---

**My thoughts:**

1. Send to database - `JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(myEditorState.getCurrentContent()))`
   Get from database - `EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(myEditorState)))`.

---

**Editors based on Draft.js:**

[react-rte](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte), [react-draft-wysiwyg](https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg), [draftail](https://github.com/springload/draftail)

Comment: **personal opinion** : i would suggest [`react-rte`](https://github.com/sstur/react-rte), this gives you another layer over `draft-js`, which provides more flexibility... and really easy to use..

Comment: [ask] but [Is This On Topic?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: instead of converting to raw, **convert to html/markdown**, so if any other client is connected to your server, without using draft-js, they can render correctly too..

Comment: Remember that the raw format isn't standardized, do it may change across different versions of Draft, so you should consider a generic format that supports the kind of content that you intend to process. It could be either markdown (as mentioned above), simplified HTML it something entirely different. It's is relatively straight forward to write your own serializer/deserializer.